# Naive Bayes v/s Logistic Regression? Which is more constrained by 'Conditional Independence' assumption?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, probability, logistic-regression, naivebayes

To my understanding, **Logistic Regression** is an extension of **Naive Bayes**. 
Suppose,

```
X = (X_1, X_2........X_N); Y = {0, 1}, each X_i is i.i.d and 
the P(X_i|Y=y_k) is a Gaussian Distribution.
```

So in order to create **Linear Decision Surface**, we take the assumption of each pdf `P(X_i|y_k)` having variance(`sigma`) independent of the value of Y i.e. `sigma_(i,k) = sigma_i`
`(i --> X_i, k --> y_k)`.

Finally we end up learning the coefficients (`w_0, w_i`) that represent the Linear Decision Surface in following eqn.:

```
P(Y=0|X)/P(Y=1|X) = w_0 + sum_i(w_i*X_i)   (Linear Decision Surface)
```

Even though the derivation of Linear Regression coefficients (`w_0, w_i`) involves the assumption of Conditional Independent `X_i given Y`,

1. Why is it said that learning these coefficients from training data are **somewhat more free** from conditional indep. assumption as compared to learning the regular Bayesian Distribution coefficients (`mu, sigma`)?

I came across this while following [this course here](https://youtu.be/z_xPu9KrgCY?t=2008).

Any clarification/suggestion would be very helpful.
Thanks